# What happens if an Index Fund sell off occurs?

Tags: index-fund, diversification

For example, if you have a 3-fund portfolio of the Fidelity Total Market Index Fund, Fidelity International Index Fund, and the Fidelity Total Bond Fund, does this strategy represent "meta" diversification? In other words, isn't this putting all of your eggs in one basket by still owning only a few different funds? What would happen to the index fund if a major sell off occurs of its shares?

Comment: Just the first one holds about $63B in assets with 1% turnover, if you have such a massive sell off of the fund that it affects the market - no diversification would help you.

Comment: The first alone holds already about 4000 stocks. Thought experiment: if you hold a fund that holds all stocks globally, you only own one asset (the fund). However, are you diversified if you hold all publicly traded stocks   in the world?

Comment: To be clear, my question isn't about the underlying stocks from the index fund having a massive sell off, but the index fund itself having a sell off and if that would affect the  fund and anyone holding that specific fund. I think @littleadv spoke to this, but I wanted to be clear of what I am asking. I appreciate the answers so far!

Comment: @w21froster the fund has no meaning, it's just a bucket of stocks, essentially. Redemption of the fund lead to fund liquidating stocks to pay the redemption. Sell off of the fund would literally mean the fund would be liquidating it's billions worth stakes in thousands of companies.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense and answers my question! I think I need to read up more on index funds. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: That should probably be an Answer. (And illustrated why the line between comment and answer is fuzzy...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comment as an answer:

The fund has no meaning, it's just a bucket of stocks, essentially. Redemption of the fund lead to fund liquidating stocks to pay the redemption. Sell off of the fund would literally mean the fund would be liquidating it's billions worth stakes in thousands of companies. Just the first one holds about $63B in assets with 1% turnover, if you have such a massive sell off of the fund that it affects the market - no diversification would help you